# Notify client in browser about destroy Spring Session on server?

Tags: javascript, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-session

How to notify client in browser by message about destroy spring session on server?

In application for Education used technology: `Spring Framework` with `Spring Security`, `Spring Session` and `Spring Data Rest` on server-side and `HTML5` with `Knockout.JS` on client side. Session timeout set to 30 min.

**Userstory:**
User is authorized, and began to fill the new document.
He left work without saving.
Come back, when the session was over, and without receiving any messages, continued to enter data into the form.
User click to save the document and received a message stating that the session has destroyed. Entered data lost :0(

Apply Websocket technology is not possible, since the channel is locked Corporate Proxy-server content filtering.

Perhaps it is necessary to link `HttpSessionEvent` and `DeferredResult` ([chat example by Rossen Stoyanchev](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-chat)). 
I have implements `HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed (HttpSessionEvent event)` for logging end the session.

I suppose that there is a ready pattern for solving such task, but i have not found the answer in the documentation [Spring Session](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/) and [Spring Security - Session Management](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-session-mgmt).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the solution you are looking for, but it still seems to me that the easiest and least invasive solution for your particular problem will be a javascript code, included on every page (if you use Tiles, you can put it in the template), which polls the server via AJAX every `x` seconds; as soon as one starts receiving AccessDeniedException, it means that the session has expired, and a suitable message is visualized on the web page. There will be a small chance that the session has expired, and the user tries to perform some action before the polling results in AccessDeniedException - the javascript code should catch then the exception resulting from user's action and visualize the same message.

Comment: Thank you, John! I will try to apply your solution in my thymeleaf template.